# Elasticsearch schema for multiple versions of the same text

Tags: elasticsearch, schema

I'm working on a system that downloads articles from various news sites and performs various NLP analyses on the texts. I want to store multiple versions and aspects of each article, including

- The raw HTML
- A cleaned-up text-only version
- [CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) output of the article.

  Since I want to store the text-only version on Elasticsearch, I thought about storing everything else on Elasticsearch, as well. I have no Elasticsearch experience, so I can't tell what's a better way to store these:

  1. Have one record per article, with the HTML, text and CoreNLP outputs as properties of that article : `{html: '....', text: '....', CoreNLP: '....'}`
  2. Store each type of information in its own type: `/articles/html/1`, `/articles/text/1`, `/articles/corenlp/1`, etc...

  Which one is more common? Is there a third, better option?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you want to do the COreNLP, the html tidy up, etc. If you want to do this in elastic I would use the multi field types:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html

If you do it outside of elastic, which would not be common since this is a good task for elastic, you could use the multiple fields approach.

Comment: What do you mean by running CoreNLP and the HTML cleanup code 'in elastic'?

Comment: What I mean is that you can use analysers to strip html characters and do some NLP tricks. That is what you can do within elastic. You can also do this externally and just provide the altered text to elastic.